# How to change the element of another div by clicking and hovering on an element of a different div

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<html>
<body>
<div A>
<button id="head">Head</button>
<button id="head">Neck</button>
<button id="head">Shoulder</button>
<button id="head">Back</button>
</div>
<div B>
<img id ="head" src="head.png"></img>
<img id ="neck" src="neck.png"></img>
<img id ="shoulder" src="shoulder.png"></img>
<img id ="back" src="back.png"></img>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to hide the  element of div B.. there are multiple items on both divs 
so for example i clicked on button with a label head only the image of a head will appear and other parts of the body will not be visible. same goes to the other parts of the body

Comment: Please do some research before asking, there are a lot of example on w3school.com that can handle your problem.

Comment: A lot of ways to do just depends on your html markup

Comment: Can you show what you have done, it would be advisable to present us with some code that you have worked on so that we can help you out.

Comment: What kind of elements in div A and what kind of elements in div B? What are the relationships? Are you limited to CSS? Is Javascript an option? How about jQuery? Please be more specific in your question and provide an example of your mark up and your best attempt so far.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like people have said there are many ways to do this. One way would be to use JavaScript event listeners. Here's a quick little demo:

```js
let change = document.getElementById("change");
let hover = document.getElementById("hover");

hover.addEventListener("mouseover", changeColor);
hover.addEventListener("mouseout", changeColor);

function changeColor() {
  change.classList.toggle("red");
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2rem;
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="change">
  Change Me
</div>

<div id="hover">
  Hover Me
</div>
```

Good luck! I'd definitely recommend on reading up on event listeners if you're not already familiar with them.